# how to delete files by batch in specific day "expiry date"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**i have *.txt files .. process every day by a batch

i want a code to add to batch

for example:

in 20.4.2016 or any date after that.
delete all *.txt in drive D:\

its like expiry date
thanks**

Comment: what part of your code do you have problems with (and what problems)?

Comment: try the forfiles command (`forfiles /?`) as a command in a for loop (`for /?`), `forfiles` let you specify files by date before or after xx/xx/xxxx

Comment: thank you .. im beginner so i dont know how to do that .. please help if you can

Comment: If I understand the question correct, that's a one-time-task to be run on 20.04.2016 (or later, if the computer don't run at that day). Sounds like a job for task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You should find your answer here...

http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

For example, this deletes log files over 14 days old...

```
FORFILES /M *.log /C "cmd /c del @path" /D -14
```

Or delete log files modified before 4th March 2016 (US date formatting for this example)...

```
FORFILES /M *.log /C "cmd /c del @path" /D -03/04/2016
```